# UIDocumentInteractionController: open file whith native application

Tags: iphone, ios

The documentation says that UIDocumentInteractionController allows to open file implicitly (UTI property is nil) with installed apps but not native.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
[controller retain];
controller.delegate = self;
//controller.UTI = uti;

CDVViewController* cont = (CDVViewController*)[ super viewController ];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, cont.view.bounds.size.width, cont.view.bounds.size.height);
[controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:cont.view animated:YES];
```

Is it possible to open for example pdf file in Safari or image in gallery?

P.S. I am new in Objective C :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to say the device  what application must open your file.

You can use 
[UIApplication's OpenUrl method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) to phone for example, or to launch Safari with some url..
For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel://%i", someNumber];
```

But if you want to open a specific file you must use `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Also there is [`QLPreviewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API to preview documents. **[Here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html)** is tutorial how to use it and to see how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `presentPreviewAnimated` to preview the file with `UIDocumentInteractionController` instead of `presentOpenInMenuFromRect`.